# Why do I need to assign this variable after call of function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, variable-assignment

I have following list, where I try to change all first characters of the keys to upper case with this code:

```
listOfNames = {
    'tim':1,
    'frank':1
}

for name in listOfNames.keys():
    name = name.capitalize()
    print(name)
```

I noticed, that when I leave out the assignment of the variable `name` like follows:

```
for name in listOfNames.keys():
    name.capitalize()
    print(name)
```

It prints out all the keys without changing them. Now if I understood it correctly, `name` is only a copy of the key. But I run the method `capitalize` on that copy. Why doesnt it return the key with upper case when I leave out `name = name.capitalize()`?

Comment: `name.capitalize()` returns a new string, it doesn't change the original one.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: In order to do replace the keys you should delete the old key and create a new key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because strings are immutable, they can't be changed in-place, so calling:

```
name.capitalize()  #  or any other method
```

returns a new string rather than modifying `name` in-place, and to achieve what you want, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
listOfNames = {
    k.capitalize() : v for k, v in listOfNames.items()
}
```